# Assigning an integer value as binary to a variable in C

Tags: c, binary

how can I assign an integer value like 111 to an other integer value but considering 111 as a binary?

For example I want to do that:

```
int x = 0b111; // x has the value 7
```

but I have the "111" saved as an integer;

what I tried to do is something like that:

```
int value = 111;

int x = 0bvalue;
```

obviously that doesn't work. So how should I do it?

Comment: `0b` prefix is not standard and is not supported by every compiler.

Comment: It doesn't work like this. BTW suppose you have this: `int value = 123; int x = 0bvalue;`. What should `x` contain now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to use hex. It is safe to assume that anyone reading your code is a programmer and therefore knows hex. Binary is however a very cumbersome format, particularly so beyond 8 bits, which is why the standard doesn't provide it - `0b` is a non-standard compiler extension.

You know for example that you are dealing with a gravely incompetent programmer when you see something like this for written for a 32 bit MCU:

```
SPICR = 0b10001111001100101010111001001111; // see manual page 666
```

People have trashed their keyboards for less.

---

If you *still* need binary compile time constants for some reason, you can either use non-standard compiler extensions that allows `0b` prefix or cook up a macro in standard C. The latter can be done as described below:

- Given a preprocessor token such as `00001111`, we can convert this to a string in the pre-processor by using the `#` "stringify" operator. Suppose we have a macro like `#define BIN(n) #n`.
- From there on, we end up with a string literal `"00001111"` which we can access like an array. So `(#n)[0]` would give us the first `'0'` digit, now in ASCII format.
- This way we can grab each individual digit. `(#n)[0] - '0'` will give value 0 or 1 instead of ASCII strings.
- If we shift this value depending on string position, we get the binary value of that digit. For example `((#n)[0] - '0') << 7` gives value 128.
- If we do this for all digits and sum the result, we get the value.

The complete macro might look like this:

```
#define TO_BIN(x) ((x)-'0')
#define BINARIFY(val, n) (TO_BIN(val) << n)
#define BIN8(n) ( \
  BINARIFY((#n)[0], 7) + \
  BINARIFY((#n)[1], 6) + \
  BINARIFY((#n)[2], 5) + \
  BINARIFY((#n)[3], 4) + \
  BINARIFY((#n)[4], 3) + \
  BINARIFY((#n)[5], 2) + \
  BINARIFY((#n)[6], 1) + \
  BINARIFY((#n)[7], 0) )
```

This can be made more flexible yet, but for now lets just add some defensive programming to ensure 8 digits integers are always used and that the macro input isn't complete garbage:

```
#define BIN(n) _Generic((n), int: sizeof(#n)==9 ? BIN8(#n) : 0 )
```

(There are still some ways to trick that macro - it isn't fool-proof but better than nothing)

Complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TO_BIN(x) ((x)-'0')
#define BINARIFY(val, n) (TO_BIN(val) << n)
#define BIN8(n) ( \
  BINARIFY(n[0], 7) + \
  BINARIFY(n[1], 6) + \
  BINARIFY(n[2], 5) + \
  BINARIFY(n[3], 4) + \
  BINARIFY(n[4], 3) + \
  BINARIFY(n[5], 2) + \
  BINARIFY(n[6], 1) + \
  BINARIFY(n[7], 0) )

#define BIN(n) _Generic((n), int: sizeof(#n)==9 ? BIN8(#n) : 0 )

int main (void)
{
    printf("%d\n", BIN(00001111)); //  15
    printf("%d\n", BIN(10000000)); // 128
    printf("%d\n", BIN(10101011)); // 171
}
```

Note that this is pure real-time and the binary calculations cost no performance or memory, unlike `sprintf` or `strtoul` calls that happen in run-time. For example x86 assembly gives

```
    mov       esi, 15
    ...
    mov       esi, 128
    ...
    mov       esi, 171
```

So the decimal values are hard-coded into the binary just as if we'd used a binary literal. And since it is compile-time calculation, we can get read-only constants just fine:

```
const int x =  BIN(10101011);
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is converting the value to string and converting back to integer specifying radix.

```
int value = 111;

char buffer[1024];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d", value);

int x = strtol(buffer, NULL, 2);
```

Another way is converting integer without converting to string.

```
int value = 111;

int x = 0;
for (int delta = 1, value2 = value; value2 > 0; value2 /= 10, delta *= 2) {
    x += (value2 % 10) * delta;
}
```

Comment: There's no apparent reason why you should do this conversion in run-time though. What if I want a read-only value?